# Tikzpicture changing axis label at a point

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have a graph like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]

\draw[->,color=black] (0.,0.) -- (10.,0.);

\foreach \x in {3} \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt)
    node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};

\draw[->,color=black] (0.,0.) -- (0.,2.);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For the x axis, I have drawn a point at `$x=3$`. I want to relabel this point as say A, instead of 3. How can I do this in this code?

Thank you

Comment: Why using a `\foreach` to draw a single point?

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]

\draw[->,color=black] (0.,0.) -- (10.,0.);

\foreach \x in {3} \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize A};

\draw[->,color=black] (0.,0.) -- (0.,2.);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```